# Puppet pass SSH keys to VM for us in Git

Tags: linux, git, ssh, vagrant, puppet

I'm using Vagrant to provision a VM onto DigitalOcean using config from PUPHPET. I need to clone a private git repo. I've created an SSH key to be used to authenticate the request using the Puppet vcsrepo module but it seems my SSH key isn't being picked up properly.

I've set Vagrant `config.ssh.forward_agent` to true and `config.ssh.private_key_path` points to my local rsa file on my mac. This is also used for the DigitalOcean key.

I can see my key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the VM.

The `git clone` fails if it's a private repo. I tried with a public repo and it is successful.

Here is the Puppet vcsrepo command:

```
vcsrepo { '/var/www/html':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'https://******@bitbucket.org/****.git',
  require    => '~/.ssh/authorized_keys',
}
```

This gives the error `No title provided and "~/.ssh/authorized_keys" is not a valid resource reference at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-893fcd`

I also tried with the identity property:

```
vcsrepo { '/var/www/html':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'https://******@bitbucket.org/****.git',
  identity    => '~/.ssh/authorized_keys',
  force => true
}
```

This gives `fatal: could not read Password for 'https://billyjones@bitbucket.org': No such device or address`

Using Debian 7.

Comment: You probably want to clone the repo over `ssh` instead of `https` if you want to use a key instead of password to validate.

Comment: https://rshestakov.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/how-to-make-vagrant-and-puppet-to-clone-private-github-repo/

Comment: You're making `vagrant` install your public key in the box. This is useful, but *not* for cloning your repo. See @Alik's link instead. Good stuff in there I think.

Comment: Thanks @Alik I'll try that link out today